# Appending to an array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to append to an array, with `.push`.
It seems that this does not happen, and here is my code.

```
if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('!startvote')) {
    let args = message.content.slice(1).trim().split(/ +/g);
    let command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    let totalOptions = [];

    message.channel.send(`Starting vote. Use !vote1, to vote for the first option, !vote2 for the second, etc.`);
    message.channel.awaitMessages(msg => msg.content.startsWith('!vote1'), {time: 10000})
      .then(collected => message.channel.send(collected.size + ' users voted for \`option 1\`'))
      .then(collected => totalOptions.push({'optionOne': collected.size}))
      .catch(console.error);
    message.channel.awaitMessages(msg => msg.content.startsWith('!vote2'), {time: 10000})
      .then(collected => message.channel.send(collected.size + ' users voted for \`option 2\`'))
      .then(collected => totalOptions.push({'optionTwo': collected.size}))
      .catch(console.error);
  }
```

Whenever I try logging this somewhere else, the array returns empty.

Edit: here is the new code

```
message.channel.awaitMessages(msg => msg.content.startsWith('!vote1'), {time: 10000})
  .then(collected => message.channel.send(collected.size + ' users voted for \`option 1\`'))
  .then(collected => totalOptions.push({'optionOne': collected.size}))
  .then(console.log(totalOptions))
  .catch(console.error);
message.channel.awaitMessages(msg => msg.content.startsWith('!vote2'), {time: 10000})
  .then(collected => message.channel.send(collected.size + ' users voted for \`option 2\`'))
  .then(collected => totalOptions.push({'optionTwo': collected.size}))
  .then(console.log(totalOptions))
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Have you put `console.log()` calls inside the `then()` calls to see if you are actually getting inside?

Comment: can you try `collected.time` instead of .size for the push? If I'm reading this right, your promise is returning an object with the property of `time`

Comment: Puttin `console.log` in the `then` immediately returns it, without waiting for the messages to actually comes through.

Comment: do you get empty array from console.log?

Comment: Yes, because the array sends before the message collector has completed.

Answer (score 0):

Because of asynchronous code, you may be outputting totalOptions befroe it's updated inside a then block.

try adding an extra then() block after the one where you push and console.log(totalOptions) in the new then().

Comment: Doing that still returns the array before all messages have been sent.